# Google does not show my website favicon

Tags: html, icons

I have added an icon to my [website](http://www.dihav.com/) using below HTML code, and it appears in all browsers, but Google does not show it (https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?alt=p&domain=www.dihav.com). Is there any idea?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="dihav.ico" type="image/x-icon"></link>
```

Comment: Google does not show it? You mean Chrome?

Comment: Can you put the icon file to website root, named as favicon.ico and try? I believe the check url you've added your question ignores in html shortcut icons and goes directly for favicon.ico

Comment: @njk I mean Google website not Google Chrome, I typed the URL.

Comment: Google shows favicons? Where? I've never seen them.

Comment: @ Roddy of the Frozen Peas https://s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?alt=p&domain=DomainName

Comment: It shows up fine for me in FF 3.6. It's a turkey?

Comment: @njk I fixed it. The icon file name must be "favicon.ico".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name it "`favicon.ico`".

Use the following code to test with this feature:

```
<SCRIPT>
<!--
 if ((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") > 0)
  (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4)) {
   var sText = "<U><SPAN STYLE='color:blue;cursor:hand;'";
   sText += "onclick='window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,";
   sText += "document.title);'>Add this page to your favorites</SPAN></U>";
   document.write(sText);
  }
 //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

[source](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-iw004.html)

Comment: Thanks, The icon file name must be "favicon.ico", it must be placed in the root directory, it must have 16x16 image, but it can have images with different resolutions too.

Answer (score 0):

mine works like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Icon/imp_icon.ico">
```

the type is not nessecairy. Further dont forget that your icon may only be 16 x 16 pixels. Else indeed it wont show.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me ... In FF too

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/ico" 
      href="images/logoicon.ico">
```